# Endpoint Address when Hosting in Window Service vs IIS

Tags: wcf, endpoint

i have a Service with a Name MyService and It implements a Service Contract IMyService

when i am hosting in IIS i have added a SVC file and a Web.config and 
provided the base address as

> http://localhost:49495/MyService.svc/

Its working fine

Now i want to Host the same Service in a Windows Service and now i am confused what should i give in base address of App config of a Windows Service

should i give Class name MyWindowService Which Implement ServiceHost

like this base address :-

> http://localhost:49496/MyWindowService/

Answer (score 1):

The base address can be anything.  As you are hosting it as an HTTP endpoint I would just make it exactly the same as your web version.  The important bit of the configuration is as follows:

`<service name="MyService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:49495/MyService.svc"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="WsHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMyService" />
      </service>`

the name is the concrete class implementation of the service contract and the contract is the interface (so MyService and IMyService in your example).

he rest is up to you - I personally don't think the client needs to care whether the service is hosted in a windows service or IIS so I would have the endpoint with the .svc so I can freely swap it around.  As long as the URL stays the same and the binding configuration also you can host it how you like.